# Невозможно переместить комментарии пользователей без учётной записи

Tags: дефект, поддержка, комментарии, инструменты-модератора, перенос-комментариев-в-чат

Хотел перенести комментарии под [ответом](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/421065/178988) в чат, но не получилось, т. к. пользователь уже удалён:

[image: скриншот]

Судя по тому, что для такого случая есть специально заготовленное сообщение, это не баг? Но тогда получается, что комментарии удалённых пользователей нельзя переносить? По мне, так это странно...

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, перенос комментариев в чат подразумевает, что продолжение дискуссии будет именно там. А так как участника дискуссии уже нет в списке живых пользователей, то и в переносе нет особого смысла.

Хотя, конечно, при условии наличия хотя бы двух живых участников дискуссии в комментариях такой перенос был бы осмысленен.

Comment: Но ведь старый диалог тоже может хотеться сохранить.

Comment: @Qwertiy почему он не может быть сохранён там, где он есть - то есть под постом?